# read Grails config parameter

Tags: grails, groovy

I've added the following parameter in `Config.groovy`

```
storeFront.cms.endpoint = "http://10.60.33.51:27110/file_source"
```

I'm trying to read it using:

```
ConfigurationHolder.config('storeFront.cms.endpoint')
```

I read somewhere that configuration parameters should be read using the `grailsApplication` variable that is available in taglibs and controllers, but in my case I'm trying to read it from a class under `src/groovy`.

When the application starts up I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.call() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [storeFront.cms.endpoint]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
ConfigurationHolder.config.storeFront.cms.endpoint
```

And yeah `ConfigurationHolder` is deprecated in Grails 2.0

Comment: any idea what we're supposed to use instead of `ConfigurationHolder` when `grailsApplication` is not available?

Comment: It's recommended that you use `def grailsApplication` injection method.  However I don't believe this injection would occur for classes in `src/java` or `src/groovy`, so I guess you'd have to pass the `grailApplication` instance in from the controller/service/etc where you call the code?

Comment: Pass the `grailsApplication` or config to the src/groovy class - it has to be called from an artifact that has access to those.