# Injecting application into resources.groovy

Tags: config, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.0.4 and would like to refer to configuration information in my `resources.groovy` file. In earlier versions of grails, I used `ConfigurationHolder` to get at this information, but this is now deprecated.

From reading other posts, I am confused about how to proceed. [One](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Using-ConfigObject-in-resources-groovy-under-grails-2-td4204499.html) suggests that the property `application` will get injected with the `GrailsApplication` bean; [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065957/read-grails-config-parameter) suggests the use of `grailsApplication`, but neither seems to work in my `resources.groovy` file.

Must I load the `GrailsApplication` bean "manually" as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133580/how-to-access-grails-configuration-in-grails-2-0#answer-10702781)? Or is there a more elegant solution? An example of a working resource file that accesses configuration information would be great.

Answer (score 10):

What did work for me was:

```
application.config.my.etc
```

I didn't even had to def application nor grailsApplication

(grailsApplication didn't work for me either)

Answer (score 1):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133580/how-to-access-grails-configuration-in-grails-2-0) already answers your question:

```
// resources.groovy
beans = {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    // So from here you could use grailsApplication to access the config object (e.g. grailsApplication.config.defaultFolder
}
```

Regards,

Luismy